# How to use multer plugin for Express (Node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I cannot get why my code return me an error?

I send a jpg file (Content-Type : multipart/form-data) to `localhost:3000/list/upload`

Maybe I'm wrong but I thing that I incorrectly use multer plugin.

Here is my Express code:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var fileName;
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser({uploadDir: path.join(__dirname, 'public/images')}));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

var m = multer({
    dest: './public/images',
    onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
        var mt = file.mimetype;
        if (mt === 'image/png' || mt === 'image/jpg' || mt === 'image/jpeg') {
            fileName = file.fieldname;
        } else {
            fileName = undefined;
            return false;
        }
    }
});

app.post('/list/upload', m, function (req, res) {
    if (fileName) {
        res.send({
            success: true,
            name: fileName
        });
        fileName = undefined;
    } else {
        res.send({
            success: false
        });
    }
});

// error handling

module.exports = app;
```

I get this error:

```
Multipart: Boundary not found
```

Comment: Can you show exactly how you are sending the request? Your request has to be in actual multipart/form-data format, so you can't just send raw image data and simply change the `Content-Type`.

Comment: The error suggests the request's body isn't formatted properly for multipart. The `Content-Type` should specify a `boundary` token that's then used to separate the multiple parts. [Example](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4). How is the request being created?

Comment: I use CocoaRestClient and set Content-Type throw that client.

Comment: I solved just adding a text field to the request.